# How can I get a value from a table into an XML without bringing in the column title?

Tags: php, xml

I'm using the following function to bring a PaymentAmount from my database into an XML.

```
    function GetPaymentTotal($orderID) {

      Global $cnx;
      $ptotal = null;

      $sql    = "SELECT value FROM orders_total WHERE class='ot_total' AND orders_id = '" . $orderID . "'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql, $cnx) or die('Couldn\'t get order ot_shipping class from ' . SHOPPING_CART . ' orders_total table: ' . mysql_error());
      if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {
          $ptotal = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
      }  

      return $ptotal;

    }
```

Using this to output:

```
$a_order['PaymentAmount']   = GetPaymentTotal($order->OrderNumber);
```

It's working, but for some reason it's bringing in the 'value' tags either side of my value... which I don't want. Here's how it looks at the minute:

```
<PaymentAmount>
   <value>74.8501</value>
</PaymentAmount>
```

Here's how I want it to look.

```
<PaymentAmount>74.8501</PaymentAmount>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've presented, the XML you dislike:

```
<PaymentAmount>
   <value>74.8501</value>
</PaymentAmount>
```

is fetched from the database. So your question suggests, that you have stored unwanted data into the database. However you have not shown how you store the data in the database with your question, so not a concrete programming example can be given how to fix storing the data.

So only the general answer seems applicable to say, that you need to change the way you store the data in the database.

From the other side you can try to fix the data when you fetch it from the database. However that seems really cumbersome, as you need to parse the data from the database first and then create a new XML Document in the format you want:

```
$dbData
    = '<PaymentAmount>
   <value>74.8501</value>
</PaymentAmount>';

$dbDoc  = new SimpleXMLElement($dbData);             # XML doc from database
$tag    = $dbDoc->getName();                         # Get tag name
$newDoc = new SimpleXMLElement("<$tag/>");           # XML doc for application
$newDoc->{0} = (string) $dbDoc->value[0];            # import value
$newData = explode("\n", $newDoc->asXML(), 2)[1];    # remove XML declaration

echo $newData; # <PaymentAmount>74.8501</PaymentAmount>
```